# MongoDB C# projection with one entry from a list

Tags: c#, mongodb

Let's assume the following objects:

```
class A
{
    string id;
    string text;
}

class B
{
    string id;
    int somestuff;
    string someotherstuff;
    List<A> mylist;
}
```

And I have a collection of objects of type B.

I am trying to do a query that returns an object like this:

```
    string id;
    int somestuff;
    string someotherstuff;
    string text;
```

where I get all the fields from B, but mylist; and I get a specific element from mylist.

doing two queries, it's quite simple, but I wonder if it is possible to do with a single query?

can I project everything and exclude mylist, but then include the proper element from mylist? or anything like this?

Comment: Try [`$elemMatch(projection)`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) to output the first matching element based on query criteria.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to perform an $Unwind to achieve what you want.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/

```
class A
{
    string id;
    string text;
}

class B
{
    string id;
    int somestuff;
    string someotherstuff;
    List<A> mylist;
}

class UnwindedB 
{
    string id;
    int somestuff;
    string someotherstuff;

    [BsonElement("mylist")]
    A myList;
}  

var instanceOfUnwindedB = await collection.Aggregate()
    .Unwind<B, UnwindedB>(x => x.myList)
    .Match(x => x.myList.id = "SomeIdOfA")
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

I assumed you have collections of A's and B's like below:

```
IMongoCollection<A> As { get; set; }
IMongoCollection<B> Bs { get; set; }
```

You could use [anonymous types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types) to achieve this:

```
Bs.AsQueryable().Select(b => new
    { b.id, b.somestuff, b.someotherstuff, text = mylist.FirstOrDefault(/*filter*/) });
```

Comment: no, there is a single collection of 'A' and 'A' contains a list of 'B'